# SQL: Order by rowID and then by column based on the rowid

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sorting, sql-order-by

I have the following `'departments'` table:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| rowid | department  | parent_department |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 10    | Main Office | NULL              |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 11    | Back Office | 10                |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 12    | Commercial  | NULL              |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 13    | Outdoor     | NULL              |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 14    | Beach       | 13                |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 15    | Gardening   | 13                |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 16    | Accounting  | 10                |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
```

and I would like to order it based on rowid and parent_department as such:

```
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| rowid | department  | parent_department |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 10    | Main Office | NULL              |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 11    | Back Office | 10                |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 16    | Accounting  | 10                |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 13    | Outdoor     | NULL              |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 14    | Beach       | 13                |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 15    | Gardening   | 13                |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 12    | Commercial  | NULL              |
+-------+-------------+-------------------+
```

So that for each **rowid**, find if `'parents_departments'` exists and show order it as the following.

Please note that I have not designed the current table and sadly I do not have the permission to change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT rowid, department, parent_department
  FROM departments
 ORDER BY IFNULL(parent_department, rowid), rowid;
```

Comment: @shmosel...nice one....but i tried out it on my local and its returning rowid in order 10,11,16,12,13,14,15

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal If there was supposed to be any ordering between parent groups, OP didn't specify it. My assumption is it doesn't matter.